# Backbone.js | How can I store elements of a view for retrieval later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, view, undefined, backbone.js

This is my first attempt at using Backbone.js, so I decided to make a simple test application that simulates a restaurant menu with menu items.  I was following along with [this cool blog post from andyet.net](http://andyet.net/blog/2010/oct/29/building-a-single-page-app-with-backbonejs-undersc/).

I'm having a problem when adding a model to a collection.  I have bound a view method to the collection's add event that should update the view.  Here is the code with as much irrelevant code removed as possible.

*(note: I removed things like local scope `var` declarations and closures for the sake of brevity.  The following is still a little long, and I know that's annoying, but it should be pretty straightforward and easy to understand):*

```
MenuItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // initialize functions removed for brevity
});
Menu = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // initialize functions removed for brevity
    // MenuSelection property is defined here.
});
MenuSelection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: MenuItem });
MenuItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // render template
});

/**
 * This is unaltered from the code.  The error occurs here.
 */
RestaurantAppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    addMenuItem : function (MenuItem) {
        var view = new MenuItemView({ model : MenuItem });
        this.menuList.append(view.render().el);
        // ERROR occurs here.  error: "this.menuList is undefined"
    },
    initialize : function () {
        this.model.MenuSelection.bind('add', this.addMenuItem);
    },
    render : function () {
        $(this.el).html(ich.app(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.menuList = this.$('#menuList'); // IT IS DEFINED HERE
        return this;
    }
});

/**
 * Everything after this I left in just-in-case you need to see it.
 */
RestaurantAppController = {
    init : function (spec) {
        this.config = { connect : true };
        _.extend(this.config, spec);
        this.model = new Menu({
           name : this.config.name,
        });
        this.view = new RestaurantAppView({ model : this.model });
        return this;
    }
};
$(function() {
    // simulating ajax JSON response.
    var json = {
        Menu : {
            name : 'Appetizers',
            MenuItem : [
                {
                    name : 'toast',
                    description : 'very taosty',
                    price : '$20.00'
                },
                {
                    name : 'jam',
                    description : 'very jammy',
                    price : '$10.00'
                },
                {
                    name : 'butter',
                    description : 'very buttery',
                    price : '$26.00'
                }
            ]
        }
    };
    window.app = RestaurantAppController.init({
        name : json.Menu.name
    });
    $('body').append(app.view.render().el);
    app.model.MenuSelection.add(json.Menu.MenuItem);
});
```

I've marked with comments the problematic area.  According the the [Backbone Documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-dollar):

> If jQuery or Zepto is included on the page, each view has a $ function that runs queries scoped within the view's element.

So, if I'm setting `this.menuList = this.$('#menuList');` in the render method, why can I not access `this.menuList` in the `addMenuItem` method?  The demo I linked to at the top does it exacly like this.  Also, if I swap out `this.menuList` for a jQuery selector, like so:

```
addMenuItem : function (MenuItem) {
    var view = new MenuItemView({ model : MenuItem });
    $('#menuList').append(view.render().el);
}
```

Everything works fine.  But I don't **want** to re-select the menulist ID every time `addMenuItem` is executed.  The RightWay<sup>TM</sup> is to cache it after it is rendered.

Also note:  I thought maybe the problem was with the ICanHaz template not returning fast enough, but then `this.menuList` would be an empty array, not `undefined`, so that's not it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're running into the #1 gotcha with JavaScript -- the dynamically scoped `this` keyword. When you pull off `this.addMenuItem` as a reference without binding it, the `addMenuItem` function loses its notion of `this`. There are two easy ways to fix it in your code, either replace this line:

```
this.model.MenuSelection.bind('add', this.addMenuItem);
```

With this:

```
this.model.MenuSelection.bind('add', _.bind(this.addMenuItem, this));
```

Or add this line to the top of your initialize function, which will accomplish effectively the same thing:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'addMenuItem');
```

Comment: `_.bindAll(this, 'addMenuItem');` did the trick.  The underscore.js documentation explained it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably addMenuItem method is being called before render method is called and hence the definition for menuList is missing in the addMenuItem.

Why don't you push **this.menuList = this.$('#menuList');**  to **initialize** method and try?

Comment: Just gave it a shot.  Still undefined.  Note, the blog tutorial has everything listed in the same order as my example.